# FtpWebRequest Fail to connect in Testing environment

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying to connect to a FTP server and getting timeout error, On my end it works but in the  test environment I get timeout error, I have disabled the firewall, replaced the url with the IP and it still does not work there

I'm using this code:

```
var remoteFTPPath = ftpServer.StartsWith("ftp://") ? ftpServer : string.Format("ftp://{0}", ftpServer);
            var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteFTPPath);
            var networkCredentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            request.Credentials = networkCredentials;
            response = request.GetResponse();
            }
            finally
            {
                 response.Close();
                 response.Dispose();

            }
```

And I'm getting an error for both active and passive mode

Active Mode:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [4784] FtpControlStream#1013293 - Sending command [PORT -----]
System.Net Information: 0 : [4784] FtpControlStream#1013293 - Received response [200 PORT command successful.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [4784] FtpControlStream#1013293 - Sending command [NLST]
System.Net Information: 0 : [4784] FtpControlStream#1013293 - Received response [150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [10856] ServicePoint#50726992 - Closed as idle.
System.Net Information: 0 : [4784] FtpWebRequest#54814357::(Releasing FTP connection#1013293.)
System.Net Error: 0 : [4784] Exception in FtpWebRequest#54814357::GetResponse - The operation has timed out.
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.CommandStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Pasive Mode

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [4784] FtpControlStream#1013293 - Sending command [TYPE I]
System.Net Information: 0 : [4784] FtpControlStream#1013293 - Received response [200 Type set to I.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [4784] FtpControlStream#1013293 - Sending command [PASV]
System.Net Information: 0 : [4784] ServicePoint#50726992 - Closed as idle. 
System.Net Information: 0 : [4784] FtpWebRequest#54814357::(Releasing FTP connection#1013293.)
System.Net Error: 0 : [4784] Exception in FtpWebRequest#54814357::GetResponse - The operation has timed out.
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.CommandStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Comment: Log into the text machine and try to connect to the FTP server using a regular client. It seems that the server is not responding to any commands after the initial connection.

Comment: thanks for your answer but is works with Filezilla

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `request.UseBinary = true;`.